# Loading images from disk with picasso, does it cache it?

Tags: android, picasso

I am planning to use PICASSO for loading images from disk (not network).

Does it do Caching as well? I dont want it to cache when it is already on desk
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading the image you can set the memory policy to NO_STORE:

```
Picasso
    .with(context)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer